# How to search for dict from a big text file using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have huge text file which I have to parse.

individual line of the file contains some text and dict. I only care about dict data.

file contain logs in the following format

```
my data : {"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}
my data : {"a":23, "b": 44, "c": 565}
my_data : {"a":1233, "b": 21, "c":544}
```

so, from above data I am only looking for dict.

I tried with

```
f = open(‘text.file’,'r’)
my_dict = eval(f.read())
```

but it gives me error as the initial part of the line is string. 
So, my question is what is the best way to extract dict from the file.

Comment: Your `f = open(‘text.file’,'r’)` line is using non-ASCII "smart quotes". See how the left quote mark curves differently from the right quote mark? Python doesn't support these. Just use regular apostrophes.

Comment: if `my_data` is written as a string (that is, it's written as `"my_data"`), then it seems your file is actually in a JSON format, which can make your life a whole lot easier: simply use the json module to decode the file, it will parse the dictionaries for you.

Comment: Your os is windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `re` module

```
import re
text = """my data : {"a":1, "b":2, "c": 3}
          my data : {"a":23, "b": 44, "c": 565}
          my_data : {"a":1233, "b": 21, "c":544}"""
dict = re.compile(r"{[^}]*?}", re.I)
matches = dict.finditer(text)
for match in matches:
    my_dict = eval(match.group())
    print(my_dict)
```

which gives you

```
{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1}
{'b': 44, 'c': 565, 'a': 23}
{'b': 21, 'c': 544, 'a': 1233}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got some delimator between the strings, so str.split() is your friend there.

Afterwards, consider using the AST module instead of the eval. It presents less of a security risk than blindly eval'ing.

```
>>>import ast
>>> a = ast.literal_eval("{'a':1}")
>>> type(a)
<class 'dict'>
>>> a
{'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

eval is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

here's what I would do:

```
import json

dicts = []
with open('text.file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line: continue
        _, dict_str = line.split(':', 1)
        dict_str = dict_str.strip()
        dict = json.load(dict_str)
        dicts.append(dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but line = f.realines will give me list..so how to use split with it